# Google Authenticator 2FA returning True always

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, google-2fa

I'm using the `GoogleAuthenticator` nuget package for `2FA` authentication in an ASP.NET application. The issue being that the function `ValidateTwoFactorPIN` always returns `true` even when the authenticator app has already changed `TOTP` code. [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GoogleAuthenticator)

[image: TwoFactorSetupRequest printed in console]

```cs
public TwoFactorSetupResponse Enable(string email)
        {
            var accountSecretKey = $"{SecretCode}-{email}";
            var setupInfo = _twoFactorAuthenticator.GenerateSetupCode("App", email, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(accountSecretKey));

            return new TwoFactorSetupResponse()
            {
                Account = setupInfo.Account,
                ManualEntryKey = setupInfo.ManualEntryKey,
                QrCodeSetupImageUrl = setupInfo.QrCodeSetupImageUrl,
            };
        }

        public bool IsCodeValid(string email, string code)
        {
            var accountSecretKey = $"{SecretCode}-{email}";
            return _twoFactorAuthenticator.ValidateTwoFactorPIN(accountSecretKey, code);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That package's default [drift tolerance](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6238#section-6) is [five minutes](https://github.com/BrandonPotter/GoogleAuthenticator/blob/65b7e24b93601e1973974cd3b9eafff1c232a578/Google.Authenticator/TwoFactorAuthenticator.cs#L24), so either test with smaller tolerance or wait until the tolerance window has passed.

Comment: Do you know how I can change that especification?

Comment: Use the overload that allow specifying your own tolerance https://github.com/BrandonPotter/GoogleAuthenticator/blob/65b7e24b93601e1973974cd3b9eafff1c232a578/Google.Authenticator/TwoFactorAuthenticator.cs#L201

Comment: Now it's returning false. Maybe I'm not doing it correctly, do you know where I can see an example?

Comment: False with what parameter? Your server and your device likely have a time difference.

Comment: Got it working after some time, thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate?  I'm just getting Invalid Code all the time.

Comment: @Deadeye I don't know anything about your code